# Кэширование, почему не может найти кэш по этому, по ключу?

Tags: java, spring, кэширование

```
 @Cacheable(value = "dishDTOs", key = "#root.methodName")
    public List<DishResponseDTO> getAllToday() {}
```

Создало кэш с ключом getAllToday, о чем я могу посмотреть в логах
Key: getAllToday | EventType: CREATED

Но теперь я хочу при методе delete этот кэш очистить

```
   @Caching(
            evict = {
                    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOs", key = "getAllToday"),
                    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "dishDTOs", key = "#dishId")
            })
```

и ловлю такую ошибку

```
Property or field 'getAllToday' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'
```

Ну и подчеркивания от идеи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, что я делаю не так